# Flash website loading screen

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have made a website in Flash using the slide presentation view and lots of Actionscript, but what I need now is to create a loading screen for the entire site to load so that it runs smoothly. Unfortunately I don't know what actionscript to use for this.

Can someone give me code snippet or an example?

Answer (score 0):

If it is Flash Professional, then just push all content one frame and use the first frame (separate key frame) of the whole movie as a loader.
If it is Flex then look for [Frame] metadata tag.